# What is the asymptotic form of $\frac {3\cos x}x-\sqrt{(\frac {\cos x}x+\sin x-y)^2-1}$ in terms of $\mathcal{O}(\frac 1x)$ as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics, approximation

I have this equation for a variable $x\in(0,\infty)$ and a constant $y\in[-1,1]$

$$  f(x)=0 ,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\\
f(x)=\frac {3\cos x}x-\sqrt{\left(\frac {\cos x}x+\sin x-y\right)^2-1} $$
with $\frac {\cos x}x+\sin x-y>1$ to get real solutions.

**My Question**

How can I write the function $f(x)$ in the asymptotic form in terms of $\mathcal{O}(\frac 1x)$ as $x\to\infty$? And then what would be the necessary condition for having real solutions?

I know that $\sin x$ is indeterminate in the limit $x\to\infty$, but, are we allowed to say that as $x\to\infty$, the function $f(x)$ behaves asymptotically in a form such as this?
$$  f(x)= -\sqrt{\left(\mathcal{O}(\frac 1x)+\sin x- y\right)^2-1}+\mathcal{O}(\frac 1x)  $$

**P.S. My major is not mathematics, so, please guide me if my question is wrong instead of downvoting:)**

Comment: Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: @Gary It is part of my project.

Comment: Along the sequence $x_n  = \pi n$ the expression under the square root tends to $
\frac{1}{4} - 1 =  - \frac{3}{4}$. How do you take the square root of $ - \frac{3}{4}$? In general, there are infinitely many intervals on the positive real line where the expression under the square root is negative. Thus, $f(x)$ is not well-defined for $x>0$.

Comment: @Gary We have this assumption that the expression in $(.)^2$ should be greater than $1$ to get real solutions!

Comment: You keep asking the same nonsesical question in different variations https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394369/the-form-of-frac-sin-2-xx-sqrt-frac-sin-2-x2-x2-cos-2-x https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396008/
We've already told you that an equation is not a function, it makes no sense to speak of the asympotic behaviour of an equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos(x)}{x}+\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}$$
$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}$ (upper limit) becomes smaller than $1$ (lower limit) as soon as $x>2$, thus disallowing real solutions in that region.

i.e. question is malformed, sadly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the question was more general; by your answer, it seems that I had chosen a bad choice of the general case. Instead of $\frac 12$, we have the general parameter $y$ varying in ${-1,1}$.

Comment: what would be your answer if instead of $-\frac12$ we had $+\frac12$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is close to those solutions of $\sin x=-1/2$ where $\cos x>0$ then $
\left( {\frac{{\cos x}}{x} + \sin x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2  \ge 1
$ so your observation is not correct. There are infinitely many solutions on the positive real line and they are approaching those solutions of $\sin x=-1/2$ for which $\cos x>0$.